How can I copy files from device external storage to application's internal storage?
Need to copy files from external storage to my application's internal storage.
I have added external storage read-write permission in manifest file.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

I can copy files with  MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. But I have to do my task without adding this permission.
Please suggest if there is any alternative way (like any shell command) to add this permission temporarily without adding it in manifest.
I have tried this for testing, I need for testing. But it didn't work for me.
adb shell appops set --uid PACKAGE_NAME MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE allow
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#enable-manage-external-storage-for-testing?

Which version of Android are you targeting? Those permissions were deprecated in SDK versions 30 and 33.

Target SDK is 33. Then I need to keep that in mind. Thanks for informing. @Philio

You did not tell how the files landed there. Who created those files? Your app? And are they media files? Android version of used device?


For testing purpose, user (who wants to test) will keep files in a folder in external storage and my app will use it. As I find no way to use the file from external storage, I decide to copy it in my app's internal storage if there is any way, 2. No, my app won't create the files, 3. it's not media file, it will be a zip file


Then your only option is ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. And once you have access to the files in the choosen folder you can copy them. But i see no need for copy as you can use the files right from that folder. Tell why you think you cant.

I don't think this is possible without that permission, you need to have MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files

is there any alternative way such as any shell command to add this permission when I need it? So that I can skip to add MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest file?

@recycle_bin I don't think so, definitely not with shell as it would be essentially bypassing the security safeguards Android has built in. You could try using Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to limit permission requests to specific folders on your external storage, but again, you need the user to grant the permission.

It will be alright to request the user to grant the permission. Let me check with this

I have tried this for testing, I need for testing. But it didn't work for me.  adb shell appops set --uid PACKAGE_NAME MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE allow
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#enable-manage-external-storage-for-testing
